# SmartGWT ~ Field Title Span Two Lines

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

Is it possible to make a ListGridField's title span two lines?

I have a listGrid with a very long title "Meets one or more Function / Job Requirement"

This is a very long title and in some cases can take room away from the other columns widths. Is it possible to force the title to span two lines?  Id prefer that given there is enough room for all the titles that this would not span two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static wrap: just insert a br tag (yes the title can use HTML).
Otherwise you could set the attribute 'wrap' on the ListGridField: you'll also need to adjust the headerHeight